# Does the position of the notify() call matter?(Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have the following situation:

```
synchronized void someMethod() {
    ...
    try {
       wait();
    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
       System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
    } 
    ...
}
```

and

```
synchronized void someOtherMethod() {
    ...
    notify();  
}
```

And the `Thread` accesses first `someMethod`, goes into `wait` and then `someOtherMethod` notifies it and returns to `Runnable` state. Does the position of the `notify()` call in the method matter? I noticed no change in behavior even when I positioned the `notify()` call at different positions inside the method.

Shouldn't the `Thread` be notified immediately when the call to `notify()` is made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position of the `notify()` call within the `synchronized` block does *not* matter because by definition, if you are still in the `synchronized` block, then you still hold the lock.

> Shouldn't the Thread be notified immediately when the call to notify() is made?

Yes.  Calling `notify()` puts one of the threads (if any) from the wait queue (waiting for the condition) into the blocked queue (waiting for the lock).  This does happen immediately, but the awoken thread needs to get the lock before it can start running.  So it is immediately moved out of the wait queue but is still waiting to get the lock.

Btw, I would recommend writing this as `this.wait()` and `this.notify()` just to be explicit about which object is being affected.

Comment: `Calling notify() puts one of the threads (if any) from the wait queue into the blocked queue. Don't you mean `Runnable` here? Awaken thread is not blocked. It is runnable waiting to be running

Comment: The awaken thread is immediately blocked waiting to get the lock.  I don't think it is in the run queue.

Comment: It can matter in a poorly designed system in the form of a missed wakeup i.e. one thread doing `if(condition) wait()` and another doing `makeConditionTrue(); notify(); doSomethingElse();`.

Comment: I don't see how this changes my answer @selig.  Can you give more specifics?  Where is the `synchronized` sections there?

Answer (score 2):

No, the position of the notify() call within the synchronized block does not matter.

I recommend the style:

```
class SomeClass {
  synchronized void someMethod() throws InterruptedException{
    ...
    while (! someCondition) {
      wait();
    } 
    ...
  }

  synchronized void someOtherMethod() {
    ...
    makeConditionValid();
    notifyAll();  
  }
}
```

Notice the use of a `while` loop around the `wait` call. Some JVMs can issue *spurious notifies*, so there is no guarantee that when a thread is notified, the original condition which caused it to wait is valid. Also, the woken up thread does not get to run until the notifying thread relinquishes the lock; so it is possible that by the time the waiting thread executes the condition is again invalid.

Answer (score 0):

These calls (i.e. `Object#wait` and `Object#notify`) need to be made within a synchronized block. Since your method is synchronized, the scope of the synchronized block includes everything within the method. Therefore, positioning is irrelevant to it.