# Notify()/NotifyAll() all before exiting synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Consider this portion of code:

```
synchronized(object) {

    ....

    object.notify(); // or object.notifyAll();

    // do something else
    doSomethingElse();

}
```

Do the Java Language specification or API commentaries or some other documentation clarify the expected behavior in this case?

Will other thread(s) be notified immediately, or only when the execution leaves the synchronized block?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11544976/179850

Comment: You are right, that's a duplicate.

Comment: I'll close it. Sometimes finding that your question is duplicate is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads will be notified immediately, but they will not execute until they have acquired control of the monitor, which in turn can only happen after the currently executing thread relinquishes control of the monitor by leaving the `synchronized` block.

The exception to this is if the current thread, with access to the monitor, yields control by calling `wait()`. In that case, any of the other threads waiting on the monitor, including the ones awakened by any calls to `notify()` or `notifyAll()`, may acquire control of the monitor and leave the original thread in a waiting state.

Comment: So, technically speaking it means that for them to be executed two conditions should be met - they should be notified and the actual lock should be released.

Comment: Point of pedantry: The lock could be released within `doSomethingElse` with a `wait` and the other threads woken up and potentially acquiring the lock before the `synchronized` block exits.

Comment: Ah, that's a fair point. I'll edit.