# notify() before exiting the synch'd block?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there **any** use in `notify()` as the last statement in a sync'd block ?

Eg.: Suppose the following code is running in some thread `r`,

```
    synchronized(t) {
        t.start();
        // do stuff using t
        t.notify();
    }
```

what would i loose if I remove the line?

```
    t.notify();
```

Thread `r` is releasing the lock of `t` already, and this lock is available to those waiting on it.

The code samples I worked on "behaved" the same with and without the `t.notify()` call up there.

The only use i can think of is, being somewhat "proactive" in notifying that the monitor of `t` is being released and those waiting on it will get into `BLOCKED` state, waiting to acquire it.
However, in this case that `notify()` is the last statement in the synch'd block, JVM will already know, by exiting the synch'd block, that this lock is released.

This rather is a Q on understanding some specifics on `notify()` & `notifyAll()`.

TIA.

Please note: I've seen [Java notify() run before wait()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537636/java-notify-run-before-wait) and [Does the position of the notify() call matter?(Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544941/does-the-position-of-the-notify-call-matterjava). This is a different Q than those.

//================================

EDIT: the sample code:

```
    public class T3 {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Sum t = new Sum();
            synchronized(t) {
                t.start();
                try { 
                    t.wait(); 
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
                }
            }        
            System.out.println("Sums up to: " + t.sum);
        }    // main
    }

    class Sum extends Thread {
        int sum;

        public void run() {
            synchronized(this) {
                for(int i = 1; i <= 55 ; sum += i++);
    //          notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

same thing when `run()` of class `Sum` is as follows:

```
        public void synchronized run() {
            for(int i = 1; i <= 55; sum += i++);
    //      notify();
        }
```

Comment: I think you're confused between just synchronization, and wait/notify. They're related, but very different. Note that you shouldn't use synchronization or wait/notify on a Thread reference, as the implementation does so itself.

Comment: It is my understanding that you would only need `notify()` if others are `wait()`ed  however in only the context of synchronized blocks, you wouldn't need it **unless** elsewhere in your program you `wait()` things

Comment: @Aaron working the same with&without notify() even when there are threads wait() ing on that object.

Comment: @JonSkeet "experimenting on the code to put concepts I place". try this.

Comment: @user3880721 "*working the same with&without notify() even when there are threads wait() ing on that object.*" would you mind posting full example which would let us reproduce it?

Comment: @user3880721 Try to remove `notify` in this example http://ideone.com/ZkLuvH

Comment: @Pshemo pls see edit. ahvnt yet tried your eg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are locking on a thread, and the thread terminates, it sends a notifyAll to whatever threads are waiting on it. See the [API documentation for Thread.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-int-):

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

In your example the notification is the last thing done before the thread finishes executing, so the explicit notification is redundant.

(Note that the API documentation quoted here and Jon Skeet are both recommending you don't lock on a thread object.)

Comment: thx - this explains. do you know what exactly are the cases that get a thread out of its WAITING state? so far it's notify()/notifyAll() and the lock itself getting into TERMINATED state.

Comment: @user3880721: a thread will get out of waiting state if interrupted, or if you call wait with a timeout, or for no reason ("spurious wakeup"). but interrupt is for canceling the thread, and spurious wakeups are rare. use the timeout if a notify may not come.

Comment: interruption gets the thread out of its `wait()` (or sleep() or join())-- i dont see how it's relevant(?) 
it is up to the thread is itself how to catch the `InterruptedException`. would come to the same thing as the thread becoming TERMINATED if that's how it is catching it.

Comment: @user3880721 it's only relevant because you asked for things that would make the thread stop waiting. it's for signalng a thread that it's time for finish, i wouldn't use it just to wake up a thread from waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It allows other threads that are `wait()`ing on `t` to run again, instead of waiting for a notify that never comes.

Comment: exiting the sync'd block doing that.

Comment: Nope, exiting a sync block doesn't perform an automatic notify().

Comment: It automatically lets the next person on queue to enter a synchronize(t) block however.

Comment: @user3880721 Please read up on wait/notify: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html